# What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site?

Tags: discussion, essential-meta-questions

*One of the tasks that we must complete in the beta is answering [the 7 essential meta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/). I'm creating these meta questions here for us to work on.*

We should begin collecting ideas and suggestions for our "elevator pitch. Create and upload your suggestions as answers, and let the voting begin!

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> - the tagline
> - the motto
> - the blurb under the logo
> - a convenience redirect “nickname” for the site
> - perhaps eventually the domain name in some form
>
> (Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely.)

The highest voted answers would be the prime candidates. I guess the final decision could be made by the moderators or in an announced chat meeting, but I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

Elevator pitch:
**Stop looking through endless pages of forum discussions. *Parenting* is where parents go for the good stuff; the best answers are always listed first because other parents have upvoted them. And when people upvote *your* good stuff, *you* earn those coveted "reputation points" too.**

It's really difficult to explain parenting.SE in fifteen seconds in a way that doesn't simply explain the SE concept but actually focuses on the benefit of *this* particular SE site! Now I know why I'm not in marketing...

---

Tagline and logo blurb:  **About the children - for the parents!**
This tagline simply but clearly states the scope and the audience. 
It could be shorter if you leave out the two *the*'s but I feel it would sound too generic that way. Replacing with *your* or *our* sounds cheesy.

---

Motto:  **Useful tools for parenting.**
Without the word *useful*, this was offered as the tagline [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/807500#807500). I think it works even better as a motto because it can be used as a yardstick for any contribution: ask yourself if this post is a useful "tool" worthy of an upvote. I want to include the word *useful* to hint at the idea that contributions should not be dumb "me too" posts but should carry some actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Tagline/Blurb: Tools for parenting.

Nickname: Parenting

Motto: ???

Comment: Motto: I'm pulling for ya, we're all in this together. :)