# Improving most googled questions and their answers?

Tags: discussion, editing, site-promotion

I encountered this question [What experts do we want to attract, and how?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200/what-experts-do-we-want-to-attract-and-how) while browsing the meta. And though I don't know how to attract experts, I have an idea how to attract people asking questions - which, apparently, is the main problem of this site.

The idea is simple: see which questions have most hits from search engines and improve them - and their answers - so that whoever encounteres them has a better chance of staying on this site and becoming a part of the community.

Of course, if there are very little people finding our questions and answers that way, there is no point of spending time on the improvements. It's up to the mods (I think) to watch the statistics and decide.

I know it's a long shot. What do you think about the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Moderators have access to a small amount of aggregate statistics. In those, I don't see any particular questions that are consistently *the most frequently searched questions.* So we would have to "focus" on any and all of them... And you know what? We already do that :-)

We have lots of high-quality answers, and we all make a constant effort to answer all new questions. I think we're already doing great with the existing content.

What we could use is *more new questions!* And it's been discussed many times already that this is hard to "invent" or fake. It needs to be a natural thing.

Comment: There have been times when the moderators go through and do a huge clean-up and edit a whole bunch of questions for the sake of improving clarity and grammar etc.  I've seen your sincere efforts!